Missing cliques in a Networkx graph

I have a connected graph that I have created using NetworkX. I am trying to find all cliques in this graph. I used enumerate_all_cliques() from the NetworkX package. This is only giving me cliques of size 1 and 2.
However, in the image below I see that a clique can be formed starting from 26-37-36-35-34-33-32-31-30-29-28-27-26. This is a full loop.
I'm new to graph theory, so what I just described above may not count as a "clique". I want to find all such loops in this graph that can start and end at the same position. How would I do that?

Please provide a [mre] of your graph (i.e. python code to reproduce it). We can't troubleshoot an image.

Cliques are not cycles but fully connected subgraphs. Cycles can be found using simple_cycles.
